# Detect when AVPlayer is playing

Tags: ios, avplayer

How do you detect when an `AVPlayer` is playing?. There appears to be a slight delay between when the `play()` function is called and the video actually plays.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, I agree with you that there is a slight delay between when the `play()` function is called and the video actually plays (In another word, the time that the first frame of the video has been rendered). The delay depends on some criteria such as video types (VOD or live streaming), the network condition, ... However, fortunately, we are able to know whenever the first frame of the video rendered, I mean exactly when the video actually plays.

By observing the `status` of the current `AVPlayerItem` and whenever it is `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`, that should be the first frame has been rendered.

```
[self.playerItem addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)path ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*) context {

    if([self.playerItem status] == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay){
        NSLog(@"The video actually plays")
    }
}
```

By the way, there is another solution where we observe `readyForDisplay` status of `AVPlayerLayer`, it also indicates whenever the video rendered. However, this solution has a drawback as mentioned in Apple document

```
/*!
     @property      readyForDisplay
     @abstract      Boolean indicating that the first video frame has been made ready for display for the current item of the associated AVPlayer.
     @discusssion   Use this property as an indicator of when best to show or animate-in an AVPlayerLayer into view. 
                    An AVPlayerLayer may be displayed, or made visible, while this propoerty is NO, however the layer will not have any 
                    user-visible content until the value becomes YES. 
                    This property remains NO for an AVPlayer currentItem whose AVAsset contains no enabled video tracks.
 */
@property(nonatomic, readonly, getter=isReadyForDisplay) BOOL readyForDisplay;
```

Here is the sample code

```
self.playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.player]; 
[self.playerLayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"readyForDisplay" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial | NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString*)path ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary*)change context:(void*) context {
    if([self.playerLayer isReadyForDisplay]){
        NSLog(@"Ready to display");
    }
}
```

Thereotically, `[self.playerLayer isReadyForDisplay]` should return YES, however, as the document, it is not guaranted.

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: I am finding it very helpful.  I am currently using "self.player!.addBoundaryTimeObserverForTimes([NSValue(CMTime: CMTimeMake(1, 20))], queue: nil, usingBlock: {()" and it isn't firing 100% of the time, I am currently looking into your solution, give me an hour and I will update if it worked, thanks!

Comment: I had to add more thing to this, and that was test that if the status is AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay AND player.rate > 0.  I needed to make sure the player was playing, but otherwise, perfect answer

Comment: @JoshO'Connor great to hear that. Thank you.

Comment: The `readyForDisplay` is very very helpful, tnx a lot for sharing this.

Answer (score 20):

**For Video**:

`AVPlayer` have an argument  called `rate (Float)`, if the `rate` is greater than 0.0, there a video that currently playing.

You can check the if the `rate` is `!=0`: (the rate can be negative if the player goes backwards)

```
if vidPlayer != nil && vidPlayer.rate != 0 {
  println("playing")
}
```

[AVPlayer class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayer/rate)

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4**

**Method 1**

```
var rateObserver: NSKeyValueObservation?

self.rateObserver = myPlayer.observe(\.rate, options:  [.new, .old], changeHandler: { (player, change) in
     if player.rate == 1  {
          print("Playing")
      }else{
           print("Stop")
      }
 })

 // Later You Can Remove Observer      
 self.rateObserver?.invalidate()
```

**Method 2**

```
myPlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "rate", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(rawValue: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new.rawValue | NSKeyValueObservingOptions.old.rawValue), context: nil)

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
      if keyPath == "rate" { 
          if player.rate == 1  {
              print("Playing")
          }else{
               print("Stop")
          }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you might want to detect:

- `AVPlayerLayer`'s `isReadyForDisplay` is when the first frame has been received.
- `AVPlayerItem`'s `readyToPlay` is when the video actually starts playing.

In order to check both status you can use observability.

You're going to have three objects defined in your class:

```
var player: AVPlayer?
var playerItem: AVPlayerItem?
var playerLayer: AVPlayerLayer?
```

The player implementation is going to be like the following:

```
guard let videoURL = URL(string: "<videoPath>") else {
   return
}
asset = AVAsset(url: videoURL)
guard let asset = asset else {
   return
}
playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset, automaticallyLoadedAssetKeys: requiredAssetKeys)
guard let playerItem = playerItem else {
   return
}
playerItem.addObserver(self,
                       forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status),
                       options: [.old, .new],
                       context: &playerItemContext)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer?.addObserver(self, 
                         forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerLayer.isReadyForDisplay), 
                         options: [.old, .new], 
                         context: &playerLayerContext)
avpController.player = player 
avpController.view.frame.size.height = playerView.frame.size.height
avpController.view.frame.size.width = playerView.frame.size.width
playerView.addSubview(avpController.view)
avpController.player?.play()
```

Here, the context are either simple integers or enum.

You can handle the events by overriding the `observeValue` method.

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                           of object: Any?,
                           change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                           context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard (context == &playerItemContext) ||
        (context == &playerLayerContext) else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath,
                           of: object,
                           change: change,
                           context: context)
        return
    }
    if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status) {
        let status: AVPlayerItem.Status
        if let statusNumber = change?[.newKey] as? NSNumber {
            status = AVPlayerItem.Status(rawValue: statusNumber.intValue)!
        } else {
            status = .unknown
        }
        switch status {
        case .readyToPlay:
            print("Ready to play")
        case .failed:
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        case .unknown:
            print("Unknown")
        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown default")
        }
    } else if keyPath == #keyPath(AVPlayerLayer.isReadyForDisplay) {
        if playerLayer?.isReadyForDisplay ?? false {
            print("Ready to display")
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove the observers.

```
deinit {
    playerItem?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerItem.status))
    playerLayer?.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVPlayerLayer.isReadyForDisplay))
}
```

Comment: `AVPlayerLayer.isReadyForDisplay` is really one of the best attributes to observe